# NSXMLParser - empty value

Tags: ios, xml-parsing

I am trying NSXMLParser for getting values from an XML for first time. But I have a problem.

Below my XML:

```
<Library>
    <Book>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <TITLE>Test</TITLE>
    </Book>
</Library>
```

and parser code:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString                                 *)   elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedNam(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
  if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Book"])
  {
    NSLog(@"%@", [attributeDict valueForKey:@"ID"]);
  }
}
```

The result ID is null. Can you help me please?

Comment: i think you have fetch you book dictionary first. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `NSXMLParser` doesn't work this way. It traverses over the elements in XML in document order, so by the time the "Book" element starts, it hasn't reached the "ID" element yet. Your code *would* work if the XML looked like

```
<Book Id="1">
    ...
</Book>
```

but I suppose you have no control over the XML. Then you need a more sophisticated solution. I believe the following would work:

Add these instance variables

```
NSString *currentElement, *bookID, *bookTitle;
NSMutableString *elementValue;
```

Implement the following methods:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString                                 *)   elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedNam(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    currentElement = elementName;
    elementValue = nil; 
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    // Append characters to element value
    if (!elementValue) elementValue = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:100];
    [elementValue appendString:string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName {
     if ([@"Id" isEqualToString:elementName]) {
          bookID = [elementValue copy];
     } else if ([@"Title" isEqualToString:elementName]) {
          bookTitle = [elementValue copy];
     } else if ([@"Book" isEqualToString:elementName]) {
          // end of Book element, do something with bookID and bookTitle
     }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. I there a way to get values to nsarray or nsdictionary, please?

Comment: i would suggest you to parse whole string first. Than according to your data structure retrieve your book ID. And yes there is a way "Parsing". Parse you string in your desired wrapper (NSArray or NSDictionary).

Comment: @ankmara I updated my answer for some guidance on this.

Comment: @HarvantS. I'm not sure what you mean. We are already parsing the string.

Comment: thank you very much. It works. Can i ask you, how add elementvalue(all) to nsarray, please? Or dic. When i use:         self.titles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[self.elementValue copy], nil] this add last object only. Thank you

Comment: You need to initialize the `titles` only once, before the parsing starts: `titles = [NSMutableArray array];`. To add objects, you can just do `[titles addObject:[elementValue copy]];`.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below code.You will understand.

In your .h part

//Step 1 : Add the Delegate classes

```
     First of all you should add <NSXMLParserDelegate>
```

//Step 2 : Create necessary objects

```
     NSXMLParser *parser;
     NSMutableData *ReceviedData;
     NSMutableString *currentStringValue;

     NSMutableArray *arrayID;
```

In your .m part

```
 //Step 3 - Allocate your all  Arrays in your viewDidLoad method

     arrayId = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];


 //Step 4 - Create Connection in your viewDidLoad Like 

     [self createConnection:@"http://www.google.com"];//give your valid url.

-(void)createConnection:(NSString *)urlString
{
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

  //Step 5 - parser delegate methods are using NSURLConnectionDelegate class or not.
    BOOL success;
    if (!parser)
    {
      parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
      parser.delegate = self;
      parser.shouldResolveExternalEntities = YES;
      success = [parser parse];
      NSLog(@"Success : %c",success);
    }
  }

   -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
  {
      NSLog(@"Current Element Name : %@",elementName);

     if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ID"])
     {
         NSLog(@"The Result is==%@",elementName);
     }

  }

  -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
  {
    currentStringValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
     NSLog(@"Current String Value : %@",currentStringValue);
  }

  -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
   {
     if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ID"])
     {
       [arrayResult addObject:currentStringValue];
     }
      currentStringValue = nil;
  }
```